# Pass a Generic Encoder for Spark groupByFunc in Java

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have a dataset `df` on which I am performing below actions in a base class.

```
class Base {
    public void func() {
      df.map(mapFunc, Encoders.STRING())
        .groupByKey(groupByFunc, Encoders.tuple(Encoders.INT(),Encoders.DATE()));
    }
}
```

I have few sub classes which extend the base class. The mapFunc, groupByFunc will be invoked for the subclasses.

The problem that I am facing is that the I want to make the Encoders used for groupByKey generic, where they can be specific for sub classes. Right now its hardcoded to return Tuple2<Integer, Date>. But my subclassess can return any number of attributes to groupBy which effectively means it does not have to be Tuple2 , it can go till Tuple5 (I know encoders dont support more than Tuple5), or even more than Tuple5.

How do you achieve this?

I tried creating an empty bean for encoder and then extending that with new encoder bean specific to all subclasses. In the groupByFunc we will have Encoder.bean(BaseEncoder.class) and in every subclass we will return object of encoder class specific to Subclass's Encoder class. But that does not work. I get below exception

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: head of empty list

    at scala.collection.immutable.Nil$.head(List.scala:420)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Nil$.head(List.scala:417)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder$$anonfun$5.apply(ExpressionEncoder.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder$$anonfun$5.apply(ExpressionEncoder.scala:120)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
```

Any other approach that can be used to tackle this scenario?

Comment: you could replace Encoders.tuple(Encoders.INT(),Encoders.DATE()) with an abstract method that the subclasses of `Base` implement

Comment: Ok this should be good, but then what would be the return type of the enclosing groupByFunct class's `call` method. Usually whatever Encoder we define (e.g. In the question, it will be Tuple2<Integer, Date>), is the return type of the call method.